# Explicit formula or estimate for a sequence of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wonder if there is  an explicit formula (maybe this is hard) or an estimate (in terms of $n$) for the recursively defined sequence:

$$s_0 = 1, \quad s_{n+1} = \sum_{i+j = n} s_is_j.$$

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: What is $n$? Is $n$ a positive integer, or any integer?

Comment: @CatalinZara Thank you.

Comment: @FlybyNight  yes

Comment: So which is it????

Comment: @A.MONET You're welcome. Something else that may be helpful for future projects: compute the first few (5-6) terms and then try oeis.org . [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences]

Comment: @CatalinZara, Thank you again... This seems to be very powerful tool !